# Get logs for oozie sqoop action from command line

Tags: hadoop, command-line-interface, cloudera, sqoop, oozie

I am having an oozie workflow with sqoop actions and I wish to get the log (stdout) of those sqoop actions from command line.

This is what I thought would work:

`oozie job -info 0000002-170819062150496-oozie-oozi-W`

which prints job_ids of actions:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0000002-170819062150496-oozie-oozi-W@sqoop-import-shard_1                     OK        job_1503124774831_0013 SUCCEEDED  -         
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0000002-170819062150496-oozie-oozi-W@sqoop-import-shard_2                     OK        job_1503124774831_0014 SUCCEEDED  -         
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

And then I use:

`mapred job -logs job_1503124774831_0013`

But this only gives the mapreduce logs. Sqoop stdout logs which I can see from `Hue` like number of records processed, --last-value (in case of incremental) are not available.

Is there a way to get them?

**EDIT:** Adding sqoop config and workflow files.

sqoop_import_config.txt

```
import
--connect
${connect}
--username
${username}
--password
${pwd}
--hive-delims-replacement
\001
--fields-terminated-by
\003
--null-string
\\N
--null-non-string
\\N
--target-dir
/data/${table}/${shard}
--query
SELECT ${columns} from ${table} WHERE $CONDITIONS
--split-by
id
--boundary-query
select min(id), max(id) from ${table}
--m
${numMappers}
--incremental
lastmodified
--last-value
${lastValue}
--check-column
updated_at
--merge-key
id
```

workflow.xml

```
<workflow-app name="${tableName}_${type}_Sqoop" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.5">
    <credentials>
        <credential name="hive2" type="hive2">
            <property>
                <name>hive2.jdbc.url</name>
                <value>${hive2JdbcUrl}</value>
            </property>
            <property>
                <name>hive2.server.principal</name>
                <value>${hive2MetastorePrincipal}</value>
            </property>
        </credential>
    </credentials>
    <start to="sqoop-import-fork"/>
    <kill name="Kill">
        <message>Action failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
    </kill>
    <fork name="sqoop-import-fork">
    <path start="sqoop-import-shard_1"/>
    <path start="sqoop-import-shard_2"/></fork>

    <action name="sqoop-import-shard_1"> <sqoop xmlns="uri:oozie:sqoop-action:0.2"><arg>--options-file</arg> <arg>${tableName}_shard_1_import.txt</arg></sqoop> <ok to="sqoop-import-join"/> <error to="email-b1f2"/> </action>
    <action name="sqoop-import-shard_2"> <sqoop xmlns="uri:oozie:sqoop-action:0.2"><arg>--options-file</arg> <arg>${tableName}_shard_2_import.txt</arg></sqoop> <ok to="sqoop-import-join"/> <error to="email-b1f2"/> </action>
    <action name="move-data" cred="hive2">
    . . .
```

Comment: Can you post your Sqoop command and `oozie workflow.xml`

Comment: @SandeepSingh Added. Hope it helps. Have you encountered such a use case where sqoop action logs are needed from command line?

Comment: yes, but I was using shell action. let me try with Sqoop action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have figured out a way to get the stdout logs after looking at `mapred job help`.

After receiving job_id from oozie using:

`oozie job -info 0000002-170819062150496-oozie-oozi-W`

Get list of attempts for the job using:

`mapred job -list-attempt-ids <job-id> <task-type> <task-state>`

- Valid values for task-type are REDUCE MAP.
- Valid values for task-state are running, completed

So I ran: `mapred job -list-attempt-ids job_1503124774831_0022 MAP completed` which gave me `attempt_1503124774831_0022_m_000000_0`

Now, I was able to get the attempt logs which had the sqoop data using:

`mapred job -logs job_1503124774831_0022 attempt_1503124774831_0022_m_000000_0`